# Creating a Stripe Summary Report

Tags: php, api, report, stripe-payments

I've recently switched payment processing to Stripe. I now need to create a report for our finance department that shows a rollup of transactions within a specified date range. I've started to create a simple PHP web page (and using the Stripe PHP library) that will give the following summaries:

- Transaction Count
- Transaction Amount
- Refund Count
- Refund Amount
- Fees
- Net

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to properly query charges with Stripe for my reporting purposes.

I know I can retrieve charges with:

```
$charges = Stripe_Charge::all();
```

And from the returned set of charges, I can compute the summary information that I need in the report. However, this will only return me a maximum of 100 charges, and I don't know how to return the charges within a specified date range.

I'm hoping more experienced Stripe developers can point me to the correct method of building the report I need.

**How can I return all charges within a specified date range?**

**Is there a better way to get this summary information from Stripe?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received confirmation from a Stripe employee that the only two options are in fact the ones described in the answers from @dwhalen and @Saikat Chakrabarti.

Quoting from the Stripe employee to the [same question I asked on Stripe](https://answers.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-create-a-summary-report-for-stripe-accounts):

> Other than the options you described (retrieving all charges, or
>   tracking in your database as charges come in) there isn't any
>   alternative way of producing the stats that you want there.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to be notified when a `charge.succeeded` or `charge.refunded` event occurs and store the relevant information in a database you control. That will give you flexibility to do the reporting you need. You can download charges that have already occurred as a CSV from the Stripe dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, this is an option. I was hoping that I could get away with not having to manage this data on my own server / database.

Answer (score 1):

You can paginate through the charges by using the count and offset parameters (documented at https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#list_charges).  I would suggest using these to process 100 charges at a time.  Then you can stop iterating through your charges once you get a charge beyond your date range.

Comment: I already considered this solution, but it can be terribly inefficient. Suppose I'm looking for 2 days of charges that occurred 6 months ago. It would not be improbable to make thousands of requests to Stripe's servers before I am sent the correct charges. I appreciate the thought, but this isn't robust enough to effectively handle my situation.

Comment: @StephenWatkins you can use the created parameter with gt / lt as documented here under the child arguments for created - https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#list_charges

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is old-ish, but.. this is now possible, a php example:

```
$charges=Stripe_Charge::all(array("created" => array("gt" => $unix_time),"limit" => 100));
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the Python equivalent to that call?

Answer (score -1):

You can use offset like

```
$return = Stripe_Charge::all(array("count" => 100, 'offset' => 0)); // set count
$return = Stripe_Charge::all(array("count" => 100, 'offset' => 100));   // set count
$return = Stripe_Charge::all(array("count" => 100, 'offset' => 200));   // set count
```