# How to get charges (transactions) details in Stripe based on date range

Tags: stripe-payments

I wanted to get a list of charges (Transactions) based on date range I specify, i.e. all transactions between my specified Start date and End date.

But in **CHARGES** API, I can not see any Start date nor End Date arguments.

How can I get this?

Comment: Similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182874/creating-a-stripe-summary-report/13227403

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Had a chat with Stripe staffs through online chat, and found that there is a way to get list of charges based on date range.

Stripe Charges API actually has some argument that are not yet listed in their documentation.

Arguments like `created[lte]` and `created[gte]` with Unix timestamp can be used, just like Events API call.

EG: `https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges?created[gte]=1362171974&created[lte]=1362517574`

Comment: This is documented now, but there are no examples.  If you are doing the request in php the array structure might look like $charges = \Stripe\Charges::all(array("created" => array("gte" => strtotime("-1 month"))));

Comment: problem is the limit, you only get 10 by default, 100 max if you define `limit` I can use pagination, but kinda weird that I have to do 10 calls just to get a total amount for a month..

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It's working for me

```
$pcharges = Charge::all(
            array(
                'limit'   => 100,
                'created' => array(
                    'gte' => strtotime('-15 day'),
                    'lte' => strtotime('-1 day')
                )
            )
        );
```

This will return last 15 days data excluding today's transaction. You can set your custom date range as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby based hack

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET']

stripe_charges = []
first_charge = Stripe::Charge.all(limit: 1).data[0].id
charge_index = first_charge
*a lot of*.times do 
  new_charges = Stripe::Charge.all(limit: 100, starting_after: charge_index).data
  stripe_charges << new_charges
  charge_index = new_charges.last.id
  stripe_charges.flatten!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Was looking in to it today and here is what i found
https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#list_charges

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges?limit=3 \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2:`

This is stripes curl example there are more examples on their website.

-James Harrington

Answer (score 1):

To get particular date data  code is like

```
$mydata= \Stripe\Charge::all(array('limit'=>50,'starting_after'=>null ,"created" => array("gt" => strtotime("2020-02-17"),"lt" => strtotime("2020-02-19"))));

print_r($mydata);
```

It will give you data of `2020-02-18` with limit `50`, If you want more record add last charge id in starting_after parameter

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please use code notation for your code

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using Ruby on Rails and is looking for a solution to list out all refunds that's been created after a Unix timestamp, using the `created.gte` syntax, here's a working example for me that I got from Stripe Support.

```
Stripe::Refund.list({limit: 100, created: {gte: 1614045880}})
```

You can change that Unix timestamp to fit your situation.

Resources: [Stripe API Reference, List all refunds](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/list?lang=ruby#list_refunds-created-gte) and [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you initialize your payment class and write a method based on listing all customers, make sure you create keys for *gte*, *lte*, *lt*, and *gt* for a dict object named `created`.

```
def filterCustomers(self, 
                    email = None,
                    created = {"gte": None, 
                               "lte": None, 
                               "gt": None, 
                               "lt": None}, #str or dict
                    ending_before = object, #object indexing
                    limit = int,
                    starting_after = object, #object indexing
                    test_clock = [] #list of customers associated with test clock
                   ):#
    customers = stripe.Customer.list(
        email = email,
        created = created,
        ending_before = ending_before,
        limit = limit,
        starting_after = starting_after,
        test_clock = test_clock 
    )
    return customers
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list